# Dialog content won't span the full width of the dialog

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, alert

I have a JavaFX dialog, and it seems the content of the grid don't span the entire width of the dialog. Right now it spans to a MAXIMUM of the the left side of the dialog, to the width of the OK button. I'd like to either remove the white space to the right of my input fields. Or span the entire width.

I've tried:

- Setting the min-width of the gridpane
- Setting the min-width of the textfields
- Setting the width of the stage

I'm pretty much at a loss here.

Here's my code!

```
// Create the custom dialog.
Dialog dialog = new Dialog<>();

dialog.initOwner(mainStage);

// Set Custom Icon
Stage stage = (Stage) dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
stage.getIcons().add(new Image(Constants.kApplicationIcon));

dialog.getDialogPane().getStylesheets().add(Constants.kRootStylesheet);
dialog.getDialogPane().getStyleClass().add("accountDialog");

dialog.setTitle("New User Detected");
dialog.setHeaderText("Please complete user registration!");

// Set the button types.
ButtonType loginButtonType = new ButtonType("Create Account", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE);
dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(loginButtonType, ButtonType.CANCEL);

// Create the username and password labels and fields.
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
grid.setHgap(10);
grid.setVgap(10);
grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));
grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
grid.setId("accountGrid");

TextField firstName = new TextField("First Name");
TextField lastName = new TextField("Last Name");

TextField email = new TextField("Email");
TextField gender = new TextField("Gender");

firstName.setId("textField");
lastName.setId("textField");

firstName.setPromptText("");
lastName.setPromptText("");

gender.setPromptText("");
email.setPromptText("");

email.setId("textField");
gender.setId("textField");

ToggleGroup studentRadioGroup = new ToggleGroup();

RadioButton mentorRadio = new RadioButton("Mentor");
RadioButton studentRadio = new RadioButton("Student");

studentRadio.fire();

mentorRadio.setToggleGroup(studentRadioGroup);
studentRadio.setToggleGroup(studentRadioGroup);

grid.add(new Label("First Name:"), 0, 0);
grid.add(firstName, 1, 0);
grid.add(new Label("Last Name:"), 0, 1);
grid.add(lastName, 1, 1);
grid.add(new Label("Email:"), 0, 2);
grid.add(email, 1, 2);
grid.add(new Label("Gender:"), 0, 3);
grid.add(gender, 1, 3);

GridPane.setHalignment(grid, HPos.CENTER);

GridPane.setHalignment(studentRadio, HPos.CENTER);
GridPane.setHalignment(studentRadio, HPos.CENTER);

grid.add(studentRadio, 0, 4);
grid.add(mentorRadio, 1, 4);

grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);

// Enable/Disable login button depending on whether a username was entered.
Node loginButton = dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(loginButtonType);
loginButton.setDisable(true);

// Do some validation (using the Java 8 lambda syntax).
firstName.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    loginButton.setDisable(newValue.trim().isEmpty());
});

dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);

// Request focus on the firstname field by default.
Platform.runLater(firstName::requestFocus);

Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

System.out.println(result.get().toString());

if (result.get().getButtonData() == ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE) {
    data.add("TRUE");
    data.add(firstName.getText());
    data.add(lastName.getText());
    data.add(email.getText());
    data.add(gender.getText());
    data.add(mentorRadio.isSelected() ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");

} else {
    data.add("FALSE");

}

return data;
```

Here's an image of the result. I want to again; either remove all the whitespace to the right of my grid, or span my grid to fit the whole width.

[Image of Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBbAP.png)

Comment: You are creating that extra space with `grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));`.  That 150 is the right padding.  See [the Insets documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/geometry/Insets.html#%3Cinit%3E%28double,double,double,double%29).

Comment: I...I... dang it! Thanks a ton! If you post an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: My goodness! It was right in front of me, thanks @VGR. Must be time for another cup of coffee for me. :)

Comment: Use `GridPane.setHgrow(firstName, Priority.ALWAYS);` to make them expand the width of `dialog.getDialogPane().setMinWidth(###);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating that extra space with `grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10));`.  That 150 is the right padding.  See [the Insets documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/geometry/Insets.html#%3Cinit%3E%28double,double,double,double%29).

Answer (score 1):

The `GridPane` is resized to it's preferred size. The padding on the right of 150 prevents the `TextField`s from growing larger in this direction.

```
grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 10, 10)); // sets right padding to 150
```

If you want to grow the `TextField`s to the maximum size the `Label`s/`RadioButton` to the left leaves, you should use `ColumnConstraint`s to specify, that the second column should always grow:

```
ColumnConstraints constraints = new ColumnConstraints();
constraints.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

grid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(new ColumnConstraints(), constraints);
```

It's also possible to specify the preferred width of the second column via the `ColumnConstraints` object.

To test the behaviour when the window size changes, you could make the dialog resizeable:

```
dialog.setResizable(true);
```

To see the area the `GridPane` covers it could be helpful to assign a background:

```
grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `setExpandableContent()` method from the dialog's pane? You can pass in whatever node you like, and then it should be able to resize to fit the entire Alert.

An example of setting a GridPane as the Alert's content.

```
GridPane() grid = new GridPane();
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
alert.getDialogPane().setExpandableContent(grid);
```

Comment: Just tried it. All it does is have it as an expandable node (hideable and non-hideable), and even breaks spacing even more. 

Although I did
`dialog.getDialogPane().setExpandableContent(grid);`
https://i.imgur.com/Wt993X3.png

Comment: I'll have to look again when I get back to my P.C., but in the meantime, have you tried: `grid.setPrefWidth(dialog.getDialogPane().getWidth());`?

Comment: Yeah. No dice unfortunately.

Comment: I hate to keep throwing blind suggestions your way, but: `GridPane.setHgrow(firstName, Priority.ALWAYS);` should let the TextFields grow out to fill the grid.

Comment: No change unfortunately. The only hint I have is that it never expands beyond the "Create Account" button. It's weird.I can set width smaller than it an I get expected results. If I try to expand it, it either expands the entire dialog (keeping that ackward spacing), or just no effect at all.

Comment: It sounds like whatever layout manager is handling the buttons doesn't allow the content of the GridPane to span them. I'm not sure how you would get around this using JavaFX's built in dialog class. I'm guessing you would have to implement a custom window instead of relying on the Dialog. EDIT: As @VGR stated, your right padding on your GridPane is what's causing the space. :)